# Dot product of a square rotation matrix to each element of another coordinate matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation, coordinate-transformation

I have a 3D matrix containing Cartesian coordinate points. In the example shown below a scaled down version of such a matrix is given (`a`) with dimensions 10x10x10x3. Then I have a rotation matrix `R` of size 3x3 and I want to make a dot product of this to each 3x1 position vector given in the matrix `a`, for example `a[0,0,0]` is the position vector for top left most coordinate point.

A simple way to do this is by using a for loop -

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones([10, 10, 10, 3])
R=np.ones([3,3])

a=np.reshape(a,(1000,3))
b=np.array([np.dot(R,xyz) for xyz in a])
b=np.reshape(b, (10,10,10,3))
```

But this is way too slow when the matrix a becomes large. Is there a way to do a matrix multiplication type thing to speed up the computation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem which speeds up the computation to more than 10 folds. But it is not a fancy matrix multiplication solution, so something that can make it even faster is always appreciated.

My current solution is the following:

```
X,Y,Z=a[:,:,:,0],a[:,:,:,1],a[:,:,:,2]
R00X=R[0][0]*X
R10X=R[1][0]*X
R20X=R[2][0]*X
R01Y=R[0][1]*Y
R11Y=R[1][1]*Y
R21Y=R[2][1]*Y
R02Z=R[0][2]*Z
R12Z=R[1][2]*Z
R22Z=R[2][2]*Z

#Rotated Field
Xr=R00X+R01Y+R02Z
Yr=R10X+R11Y+R12Z
Zr=R20X+R21Y+R22Z

b=np.array([Xr,Yr,Zr]).T
```